# Share Dropbox folder with Javascript SDK V2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sdk, dropbox-api

I'm trying to implement service in my Angular 2 application that will work with Dropbox service with Javascript SDK V2. My model looks like this:

```
User create folder with photos -> in app user share folder
```

How to implement method that will share this folder, if folder haven't `shared_folder_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a folder isn't already shared, you can use the [`sharingShareFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingShareFolder__anchor) method in the official [Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) to share it.

You can then use [`sharingAddFolderMember`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingAddFolderMember__anchor) to invite other users to it.